# I am getting a syntax error when I query a regex using sequelize and node

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am facing a problem when I query data that does not follow a regex. My backend is all set and working well but when I test this controller:

```
exports.getInvalidPhone = (req, res, next) => {
  sequelize
    .query(
  "SELECT * WHERE distination_phone NOT REGEXP /^(009665|9665|+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/ ",
      { type: QueryTypes.SELECT }
    )
    .then((result) => {
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

I get this error

> DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near
> '/^(009665|9665|+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/' at line 1

Comment: Don't forget the `''` :)

Comment: Do you mean to put the regex between quotes? I've tried to do it but it raised an error

Comment: Yes. Could you [edit] your question and post what error appears?